# Libgdx - TexturePacker combination of texture filters

Tags: java, android, filter, libgdx, textures

apologies as this is a common topic and haven't found a widely-agreed on solution.

We have a game world "grid" size of 1220 x 1080 (based on our Designer's photoshop designs). Currently we test on a Nexus 4 (1280x768 @320DPI) and TF201 Transformer Prime Tablet (1280x800 @149DPI).

When packing textures, with the TexturePacker, we're a bit confused about which combination of filters to use. We've read the following page:

http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1403

.. and when using "Nearest, Nearest", our FPS was fine at 60, but assets became pixelated. Now we packed using "Mipmap, Mipmap", and our FPS went down to 30, but the textures are smoothly edged again.

Is there an agreed upon combination of these filters, or are they simply dependent on requirements? There are quite a lot of combinations to set for "min filter" and "mag filter" in the Packer, so don't want to keep randomly setting them until everything is smoothly resized and FPS is high again, without fully understanding what it is doing.

Many thanks.
J

Comment: Linear linear without mipmaps is usually enough if you dont zoom and scale your sprites a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you are supporting multiple screen sizes (which you are if targeting Android), the Mag filter should always be Linear. There is no such thing as a mip-mapped mag filter, and on some devices that won't even work (you'll get pure black). It's kind of a "gotcha", because some devices will just assume you meant Linear and fix it for you, so if you fail to test on a device that doesn't do this for you, you'll be unaware of the problem. Nearest will look pixelated when stretched bigger, and you would only want to use it if your are doing retro low resolution graphics, or drawing something pixel perfect.

You can choose one of the following for the Min filter, from fastest (and worst looking) to slowest (and best looking):

- Nearest - this will look pixelated and I can't think of any situation where this would be the right choice for a min filter.
- MipMapNearestNearest - Won't look or perform better than nearest, and uses more memory. No reason to ever use this.
- MipMapNearestLinear - Gets the nearest pixel from the two nearest mips and then linearly interpolates between them. This will still look pixelated. I don't think this is ever used either.
- MipMapLinearNearest - Gets the nearest mip level and linearly determines the pixel color. This is most commonly used on mobile for smooth graphics, I think. It performs significantly faster than the below option, but there are cases where it will look slightly blurry (when the nearest mip is kind of on the small side for what's on screen).
- MipMapLinearLinear - Gets the two nearest mip levels, linearly determines the pixel color on each of them, and then linearly blends between the two. If you have a sprite that shrinks from nothing to full size, you probably won't be able to detect any difference in quality from smallest to largest. But this is also slow. In the past, I have limited its use to my fonts. I have also done one project that could run at 60fps on new devices three years ago, where I used this on everything. I was very careful about overdraw in that app, so I could get away with it.

Finally, there's linear filtering, which looks **and** performs worse than the mip-mapping options (for a Min filter):

- Linear - this will look smooth if the image is slightly smaller on screen than its original texture. This doesn't use up the 33% extra texture memory that mip mapping does, but the performance will be worse than it would with mip mapping if the texture gets any smaller than 50% of the original, because for each screen pixel it will have to sample and blend more than four pixels from the original texture.